# New files from shared folder not showing up on remote PC

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I have a shared folder on my Win 7 desktop, and I access it from Win 8 laptop. I don't use homegroup because I couldn't get it working, have workgroup set up on both PCs (don't know if it's relevant to the question). It mostly works fine, with 1 exception: when a new file is added to a shared folder on the desktop, it's not there on laptop. All other files / folders are, but not the ones I've just created. I can't figure when it actually updates the list, but think it's when I restart the PC. Any ideas on fixing this issue, or at least on how to force it to refresh without rebooting either of the PCs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue for some time.

MS tried to fix it for Windows 7 with this hotfix:

**File that a user adds to a remote folder is not displayed in Windows Explorer on a computer that is running Windows 7**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2769790/en-us

But this hotfix never worked for me and I also have this in Win8. The only workaround that really works is to create a temp folder in the share and delete the folder again.

Comment: So deleting a folder forces it to refresh the list? Because I've tried mere creating to no avail. Anyway, ty.

Comment: I thin the combination of create + delete causes the refrsh. For me this helps.

Comment: Do you have to create and delete a folder on local or remote computer? I've tried doing on the PC that hosts the folder and it doesn't help. Can't do from remote laptop cause the folder is read-only.

Comment: you have to do this on the PC which hosts the share. This works for me.