# Files created in shared folder default to invisible

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-sharing, shared-folders

Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.

I create a folder F:\Foo, and share it via "Share With" > "Homegroup (Read/Write)"

I create a file in this folder: either by dragging from a flash drive , or for the purposes of this post, by going `copy con a.txt` and typing some stuff.

I have a Windows 8 laptop also. The laptop can view `Foo` on my PC , however it cannot see `a.txt`. If I list permissions in Cygwin, it shows as:

```
-rwx------+ Matt 5 May  5 02:22 a.txt
```

If I go `chmod a+rx a.txt`, then the laptop can now see `a.txt`

It is annoying that I have to `chmod` every file I copy into the shared folder, I'd like to be able to put files there and then have them visible on the network share by default, without having to chmod.

My question is: how do I configure the share so that the files default to visible?

I googled this problem earlier and it suggested using `icacls` as a diagnostic. Here is the output before doing `chmod`:

```
a.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
  Matt-PC\Matt:(I)(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  Matt-PC\HomeUsers:(I)(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
```

And after `chmod`:

```
a.txt Matt-PC\Matt:(M,WDAC,WO)
  Matt-PC\None:(RX)
  Everyone:(RX)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
  Matt-PC\HomeUsers:(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
```

Extra question: what does the `(I)` indicate here? It's not listed in the [official documentation for icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx).

The laptop connects by doing `\\192.168.1.99\Foo`, and no username/password required (This is how I want it to be).

I tried the idea of creating and deleting a folder as suggested on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/622176/new-files-from-shared-folder-not-showing-up-on-remote-pc), however that did not cause the permissions of `a.txt` to change.

Comment: Rather then sharing with your Homegroup, choose **Share with > Specific people**. Type `Everyone` and press Enter. Then choose the permission level, and click **Share**.  As for the `(I)` permission, it's actually documented in the command help (`icacls /?`). It means `permission inherited from parent container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Rather then sharing through a [homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-a-homegroup), follow these steps:

1. Right-click the folder, and choose **Share with > Specific people** from the context menu.
2. Type `Everyone`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Select either the **Read** or **Read/Write** permission level, as needed.
4. Click **Share**.

---

As for the `(I)` permission, it's actually documented in the command help (`icacls /?`). It means `permission inherited from parent container`.